# Unable to build multi-page Vite app with React + TS - How to display other html pages?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm just trying to work in my dev environment right now.

I've been trying to follow their docs: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app

So creating new folders, with a .html and a .tsx in each, then reference them in the vite.config.ts as such:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src');

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: { proxy: { "/api": "http://localhost:5000/" } },
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        // main: "./src/index.html",
        // login: "./src/pages/login.html"
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
        login: resolve(root, 'pages', 'login.html'),
        test: "test/index.html"
      }
    },
  },
});
```

But it's not working. I understand also that this part is important mainly for production build.

What am I missing, even just in my dev environment??

Right now, the entry point of the app is `./index.html` (if I move it to the `./src folder`, my app won't work anymore)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/modo.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="src/main.tsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

references to `./src/main.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

But if I create a `./test/index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/modo.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">iiejfhiewh</div>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <script type="module" src="Test.tsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

referencing the `./test/Test.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('test')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

It's not working when I try to go to the address

```
http://127.0.0.1:5173/test
```

It just keeps showing the main entry point page

Ideally, I'd like all my pages to be in `./src/pages`, and have in there for example `index.html`, `login.html`, etc.

And to access them, simply

```
http://127.0.0.1:5173

http://127.0.0.1:5173/login
```

...

Another thing: If I try to move the main `index.html` into the `/src` folder, landing on the home page `http://127.0.0.1:5173` for me, it shows nothing. It seems my app can and will only show the index.html if it's in the root directory of the project. No other ones.

PS: How do you show the tree structure of a project?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.

I found out the route should be exactly http://127.0.0.1:5173/test/

not http://127.0.0.1:5173/test.

Need a slash behind the url.